# Monkey Patch Instance Method Not Working in Python Multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, monkeypatching

I am trying to monkey patch an instance `foo` with the function `baz` to overwrite the instance method `foo.bar`. This works initially without involving `multiprocessing`.

**Works without `multiprocessing`**

```
def baz(self, n):
    print('Baz' + str(n))

class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        print('Foobar')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo = Foo()
    foo.bar()       # Output: Foobar

    foo.bar = baz.__get__(foo)
    foo.bar(0)      # Output: Baz0
```

**Problem:** However, if we were to pass the monkey-patched `foo` instance into `multiprocessing.Pool`,

```
import multiprocessing

multiprocessing.Pool(2).map(foo.bar, [1,2,3])
```

we get the error

> AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'baz'

Why is this happening, and how can we solve it?

**Full Code**

```
import multiprocessing

def baz(self, n):
    print('Baz' + str(n))

class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        print('Foobar')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo = Foo()
    foo.bar()       # Output: Foobar

    foo.bar = baz.__get__(foo)
    foo.bar(0)      # Output: Baz0
    multiprocessing.Pool(2).map(foo.bar, [1,2,3])   # AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'baz'
```

*Using Python 3.7.4 on Mac OS X 10.15.2 Catalina*

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: What OS do you use? We have this issue on mac only. Didn't manage to solve it.

Comment: @pablete Did not solve it yet

Comment: @sur0k I'm using Mac OS X.

Comment: not yet, was using win32 python 3.7